# Nonhomogenous Differential Equation of Bessel Type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to solve the differential equation: $x^2y''+xy'+(-1-x^2)y=f(x)$ with $f(x)=x$, $f(0)=f(1)=0$.  We're supposed to use the previous problem (for which we did an eigenfunction expansion of $f(x)=x$ with the equation $x^2y''+xy'+(\lambda x^2-1)y=f(x)$ (same boundary conditions.

When I did that eigenfunction expansion, I got that there are no negative eigenvalues, (since when we consider $\lambda<0$, $\lambda=-\mu^2$, we get a solution of the form $y(x)=c_1I_1(\mu x)+c_2K_1(\mu x)$.  In order to satisfy the boundary conditions, $c_1=c_2=0$, (since for small x, $c_2K_1(\mu x)=\dfrac{c_2}{\mu x}$, so $c_2=0$ and for larger x, $c_1I_1(\mu x)=\dfrac{c_1 e^{\mu x}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \mu x}}$, so $c_1=0$)).  Therefore for any negative lambda I get the trivial solution.

So would I only get a particular solution for the equation $x^2y''+xy'+(-1-x^2)y=x$?

Not looking for a complete answer, just a thought as to whether or not my thought process is right, or where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2y%22%2Bxy%27%2B%28-1-x%5E2%29y%3Dx, the inhomogeneous part can be expressed as $-\dfrac{i\pi(J_1(ix)Y_0(-ix)+J_0(ix)Y_1(-ix))}{2}$ .

Comment: hmm, it gives a solution for the homogenous part, so i guess my initial conclusion that there are no negative eigenvalues for that one problem is incorrect.  thanks!